# Role concept in the authorization

Tags: java, security, authorization

I'm writing the following

```
public interface SecurityService{

    public Error tryLogin(String usr, String psw);

    public String getRoleCurrentUser(); //Attention here
}
```

and of course, there will be a couple implementations. For instance, now I have

```
public SpringSecurityService{

     @Autowired
     AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

     public Error tryLogin(String usr, String psw){
         //Implementation here
     }

     public String getRoleCurrentUser(){
           String role = null;
          //Getting the role of the current user
          //and if the user authorized 
          //assigning it to the role local variable
          return role;
     }
}
```

In the `SecurityService` interface I used the role concept. My question is if the using of the role-concept couples the code to the spring-security?

Or the role-concept is a strictly criptographic concept, so any security framework which takes care of the authorization should understand the role concept.

Comment: Roles are a widely used concept and thus wouldn't couple your implementation to spring. One thing I'd suggest though: keep in mind that users might have/need multiple roles or you could end up with as many roles as you have users in the worst case.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for the comment. I think it's reasonable to ask if there's a security framework that doesn't use roles?

Comment: Yes there are, at least frameworks that also support permissions (i.e. objects/assets and operations allowed on those). One example would be [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/). Another seems to be [OACC](http://oaccframework.org/).

Comment: @Thomas So in case of migrating to such a framework I will have to change the interface or create another one to make authorization works?

Comment: That depends on how you're actually doing the authorization checks. There might be ways to do it in a somewhat transparent way (most probably based on AOP to intercept access to methods/assets) but since both concepts are quite different it's not that easy. You could have a look at how Shiro does it in order to get an idea.

Comment: Btw, here's link to a presentation on another framework which seems to also address some of the problems with role-based authorization: http://de.slideshare.net/rdebusscher/octopus-framework-permission-basedn

Comment: @Thomas That's I might call the interface `RoleBasedSecurityService` instead. Would it sound ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest against implementing your own logic. Just search around in SO for many failed attempts.

There are plenty of frameworks that let you do just the right level of access control you are looking for. Some are even mentioned in the comments.

Have a look at:

- Spring Security
- Apache Shiro
- WSO2 IS

which are all open source solutions for authentication and / or authorization.

At a broader level, read up on the two prevalent authorization models out there:

- role-based access control ([rbac](/questions/tagged/rbac) - [NIST definition](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/SNS/rbac/))
- attribute-based access control ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac) - [NIST definition](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/))
- [XACML](http://www.axiomatics.com/pure-xacml.html) is a standard which implements ABAC.

Comment: I think you didn;t understand. I was not going to implement it on my own, I jus needed in a wrapper for the functions. That's why I wsa interested in the thing.

Comment: Ah I get it, like a facade or a business model to authorization model mapper?

Comment: Exactly, but in fact I called my service as `RoleBasedSecurityService`. Hope it was clear